# Linux Mint 20 Wi-Fi adapter cable not plugged in

Tags: networking, wifi

this is a self built computer, I have a wifi adapter that works in Windows and has a Linux driver. I have installed it, but no matter what I do the wired cable unplugged in networks is the only item I see. I have to tether on my phone to get internet connection. I have followed the step by step guide on Realtek to install the driver manually and it still will not detect. This is an RTL8111/8168. `dkms status` seems to have nothing there when executed. I also have a usb bluetooth adapter that is working fine. The wifi adapter is not working.

Here is the `rfkill` output:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the `sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
yoshi@Luccio:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for yoshi:             
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: a8:a1:59:11:4b:10
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.03-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:47 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcc04000-fcc04fff memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff
```

and here is the `ifconfig` output:

```
yoshi@Luccio:~$ ifconfig
enp8s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a8:a1:59:11:4b:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 47  base 0x1000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16480  bytes 1233200 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16480  bytes 1233200 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Please assist.

Sorry it is not letting me actually embed the images,

Here is the lsusb

```
yoshi@Luccio:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c248 Logitech, Inc. G105 Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0060 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Lancehead Tournament Edition
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the dmesg

https://pastebin.com/uabfiu8J

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It's usually better to insert error messages as text. The advantage is that your question can be found by others who run into the same error message. Note that you can edit your question and [format them as code blocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) at any time.

Comment: (1) Please post text as text.   If you really *really **REALLY*** can’t copy and paste the output, then transcribe it and include the links to the images for reference.   (I did the short one for you.)   (2) It would probably help if you told us more about your problem.   What kind of computer; what kind of Wi-Fi adapter?   Is this a brand new computer, where Wi-Fi has never worked?   (Can you take it back to the place you bought it?)   Is this an old computer where Wi-Fi has worked, but you’ve just installed Linux Mint for the first time?   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Has Wi-Fi been working with Linux Mint, and it just suddenly failed?  Did anything change?  (Software update?)  Is your computer configured to use DHCP?  Do you have a DHCP server?  Etc. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Sorry for the problem. This should be better.

Comment: It is not the bluetooth device though, it is a wifi device. I do have a bluetooth device in the system as well, but it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

Hi It seems to be a problem with the 5.4 kernel.
Install 19.3 Linux Mint with 4.6 kernel and wait until 5.8 kernel comes out.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind adding a link to the reference where you have found that information?